# Unable to execute stored procedure using Mule 4

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave

I am trying to execute store procedure but getting below error, Please someone help me on the same.

Error:

```
ERROR 2020-01-17 18:13:55,573 [[MuleRuntime].cpuIntensive.01: [imf.org].imf-orgFlow1.CPU_INTENSIVE @d5e7f1] [event: 1ee63c30-3955-11ea-aeb0-000d3a9f109e] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.exception.OnErrorPropagateHandler: 

********************************************************************************

Message        : "You called the function 'Value Selector' with these arguments: 

 1: String ("{\r\n\t\"CountryCode\": \"IND\",\r\n\t\"CategoryIds\": \"1\",\r\n\t\"Years\"...)

 2: Name ("CountryCode")

 But it expects one of these combinations:
(Array, Name)
(Array, String)
(Date, Name)
(DateTime, Name)
(LocalDateTime, Name)
6| CountryCode: payload.CountryCode ,

         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: You need to provide more details. You should share the input payload the Database operation (in XML form) and which element failed in the flow (it is included in the error message) however the error points to a DataWeave type error rather than any database issue. Is this happening before, during or after the stored procedure execution?

Comment: From the error it seems the payload is a String and not being considered as JSON. You should check where that data is coming from.